# Consistency of OLS estimator

Tags: regression, least-squares, econometrics, asymptotics

Under some assumptions, OLS estimator is consistent to true value. With all the assumptions hold, now I would like to know if OLS estimator calculated from subset of sample is still consistent or not.

To be precise, does consistency of these two estimator hold?

1. beta_1: calculated using only every two observation.
2. beta_2: calculated after removing outliers.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Regarding the removal of outliers, how do you define outliers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.